# Some tag changes needed related to Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

So [this](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-Certified-Kubernetes-and-Google-Kubernetes-Engine.html) has just happened, which necessitates some tag changes here.

Could someone with the appropriate permissions (I don't yet have enough rep to do so) kindly create tag [google-kubernetes-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine), and set [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine) and [gke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gke) as synonyms thereof? (This also needs to be done on Serverfault.)

*(Edited for clarity and taking feedback into account)*

Comment: I believe the way to go would be to create `[google-kubernetes-engine]`, then assign the other tags as synonyms of the new one. You can't just "rename" tags.

Comment: I don't have the perms for it, which is why I'm posting here.

Comment: I realize that. I'm just (incorrect in) pointing out that there's technically no way to "rename" tags.

Comment: @Cerbrus well *technically* a mod can merge a tag into another tag (which doesn't have to exist) which is effectively a *rename* :)

Comment: @JonClements That's what I was referring to -- my apologies for the poor nomenclature on my part. ;)

Comment: @JonClements: Aw shoot. My bad :P

Comment: If you think it needs doing on Server Fault as well, then please raise a question on their meta - https://meta.serverfault.com

Comment: @ChrisF [Done](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9204/some-tag-changes-needed-related-to-google-kubernetes-engine), thanks!