# Clean-up tag synonyms around [google-kubernetes-engine], in particular [gke]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I was looking at the [gke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gke) tag, specifically as there was a stream of new questions posted to it today, and it seems like there is a bit of a stalemate around tag synonyms for Google's Kubernetes Engine product on Stack Overflow.

Could either eligible users for [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine) (the original name of this product) please upvote both existing tag synonym proposals or a mod please take a look?

I'm new to this process and Meta, so happy to receive clarification of the processes for either if that's not appropriate :)

---

Rationale and explanation:
[gke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gke) is a very clear synonym of [google-kubernetes-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine), I found a [previous meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359392/some-tag-changes-needed-related-to-google-kubernetes-engine) that seems to describe the situation pretty well. As this linked question is now over a year old and still causing issues for new posters, seems best to ask a new question, providing more background.

I suspect the timeline of events has caused this situation, here it is, with question counts at time of writing:

1. [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine) is initial product name (1122 questions)
2. [google-kubernetes-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine) starts due to Google renaming the product (867 questions)
3. [gke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gke) is a shorthand for 2. above which is not the easiest to remember. (420 questions)

Because of the timeline, [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine) has synonym proposals for both other tags. But they are stuck on 0 and 1 votes.

[image: Current voting on google-container-engine synonyms]

Comment: IMHO [google-kubernetes-engine] should be the canonical tag. I've started a new discussion at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383008 on this topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they both are the same. I checked most of the questions in allof the tags, and  approved both the synonyms after making sure that there wasn't any other usage. Given that GKE was an acronym, I was concerned if it was being used for some other abbreviation, but it wasn't.

I synonymized the tags in the following manner:

- [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine) × 1122  ← [google-kubernetes-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine) × 874 (which was proposed on Dec 4 '17)
- [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine) × 1122  ← [gke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gke) × 427  anon (which was proposed on Oct 28 '17)

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed that the topuser stats for the tags seem to be stuck, even though there have been a low but steady stream of new questions coming in ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-container-engine/topusers). Is that something that will sort itself out, or does it need further attention?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts, I think it is just caching and will fix itself in a few days. Ideally it should have been updated by now, but let's just give it some more time.