# Should [google-kubernetes-engine] be the canonical tag about Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I see that the synonym [was approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380358/clean-up-tag-synonyms-around-google-kubernetes-engine-in-particular-gke) on Feb 20, but it seems strange that the old name (Container Engine) was chosen as canonical over the new name (Kubernetes Engine).

I assume, and Bhargav Rao can correct me if I'm wrong, that this was just because the older tag name had more questions given its age. Given that Google Kubernetes Engine is the current name, and that [google-kubernetes-engine] is the tag which Google [links to](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/stackexchange), should the synonyms be flipped so that [gke] and [google-container-engine] both point to [google-kubernetes-engine]?

Comment: It was synonymized in that direction because Robert Bailey, a top user in that tag proposed it in that direction. I can swap the naming, if the community feels that it makes more sense in thee other direction.

Comment: I think it does make more sense to use the current (and hopefully definitive) product name as the "canonical" tag.

Comment: I think that Robert Bailey's proposal made sense at the time it was created, but a year after the rename it's probably worth reversing. Community *seems* to agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment before, the top user in the tag Robert Bailey proposed it to be in that direction, and therefore it was created that way. However, given the community's approval in this post to swap the synonyms, as well as Alex's comment (Alex is a gold badge in [google-app-engine], a related tag), I have now swapped the direction of the synonym.

One issue was that the tags were just added as synonyms and therefore simple swaps wouldn't have been a neat solution. The tags had to be merged instead.

Another issue here was that Janos Lenart, another top user of the tag, had added [gke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gke) as a synonym to [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine). Therefore that had to be removed and instead synonymized to [google-kubernetes-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-kubernetes-engine).

I have now done all of this now, and the tag is ready for use.